# How to speed up the unzip action on windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, zip, unzip

When I used the [SharpZipLib](http://slsharpziplib.codeplex.com/) to unzip a zip file which has 5000 files on the windows phone 7. It took more than 5 minutes to finish it.
Here is the code:

```
using (StreamReader httpwebStreamReader = new StreamReader(ea.Result))
            {
                //open isolated storage to save files
                using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    using (ZipInputStream s = new ZipInputStream(httpwebStreamReader.BaseStream))
                    {
                        //s.Password = "123456";//if archive is encrypted
                        ZipEntry theEntry;
                        while ((theEntry = s.GetNextEntry()) != null)
                        {
                            string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(theEntry.Name);
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(theEntry.Name);

                            // create directory
                            if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                            {
                                isoStore.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                            }

                            if (fileName != String.Empty)
                            {
                                //save file to isolated storage
                                using (BinaryWriter streamWriter =
                                        new BinaryWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream(theEntry.Name,
                                            FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Write, isoStore)))
                                {

                                    int size = 2048;
                                    byte[] data = new byte[2048];
                                    while (true)
                                    {
                                        size = s.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                                        if (size > 0)
                                        {
                                            streamWriter.Write(data, 0, size);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Why it's so slow?
How can I speed up the unzip action?
Anyone knows?

Comment: Does mulitthreading work on this?

Comment: Is this in the emulator or on a device? How do the times compare between the two?

Comment: the time on my nokia 800 was more than 5 minutes, but in the emulator it tooks only 20 seconds!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to increase your buffer size. Change the lines

```
int size = 2048;
byte[] data = new byte[2048];
```

And change the `2048` to something like `32768` (32*1024).

A 2KB block size is making a lot of individual writes to the flash storage. In my experience that's a somewhat slow thing and can vary from device to device. A 32KB block size should do 16 times fewer but I don't know if that will result in a direct 16x speedup. I'm interested to hear back.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.I change the size to 32768 and it takes 3 minutes. I think the zip file has so many small files such as 2KB, 3KB .Is that the point?

Comment: Even if it was one large file in the zip file, a small buffer size of 2KB like you were using would slow it down. The next thing to try is to read the data in a loop but don't write it to the disk. Then you can see if the bottleneck is processing the zip file or if it's writing the files to the disk. My guess is writing the files to disk is the slow part, and in that case having many files in the zip slows you down more. Let me know how that test goes.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I change the file stream to the memory stream.But it seems doesn't work...So I change the unzip action to another thread and it seems well but sometime the main thread will frozen...How can i dispose the unzip threading?@.@